# Can i set a same NTP server twice by using IPv4 and then IPv6 address of the same server

Tags: ntp

can I set same NTP server twice i.e one by using IPv4 address and other by using Ipv6 address of the same NTP server?

for example :

lets suppose we have a NTP server named as XXX. Now this XXX server will have both IPv4 and IPv6 address.. right?... now can i set a same server twice by using ipv4 address and ipv6 address at same time

Comment: What ist your definition for "set the same server twice", i.e. what are you hoping to accomplish?

Comment: lets suppose we have a NTP server named as XXX. Now this XXX server will have both IPv4 and IPv6 address.. right?... now can i set a same server twice by using ipv4 address and ipv6 address at same time

Comment: It would depend on the OS, however if the v6 address is down, so is the v4 address (on Linux and windows at least) so there would be little benefit.

Comment: I still do not understand the point of this exercise. Put the name of the NTP server in, it will resolve one or the other.   Pointing at the same clock twice doesn't make your timekeeping better.

Comment: Indeed. Listing the same server twice will make your timekeeping _less_ reliable. This is not a good idea.

Comment: yes i agree.. i just want to know whether we can set the same server twice by ipv4 and ipv6 address

Comment: Is there something wrong with my answer?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can do this with the ntp reference implementation. Use the `-4` and `-6` directives in your config:

```
server -4 XXX.example.com
server -6 XXX.example.com
server pool.ntp.org

# blah blah rest of config
```